# Captcha on login form using the form block module

Tags: 7, forms, security, captcha

I am providing the registration form using the form block module. I also have Captcha and Hidden Captcha module enabled on mysite. However i am not getting the option to add a captcha to the registration  form which is coming from the Form Block Module. How can i do so...i tried to find the form id of this registration block (form the form block module) but was unable to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried through firebug

Comment: yes but i do not find it